# QtDesigner - Two identical Comboboxes having different sizes

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt5, qt-designer

im working on a small test programm (a translator) to get into QtDesigner.
This is what it looks like in the designer:

[image]

As you can see, the two Comboboxes have different width - i did not change any width values manually, i only changed the alingment and the layout. the entire left half and the right half are IDENTICAL apart from the text, *except* that the left text field is a QTextEdit and the right one is a QTextBrowser.

It seems to have nothing to do with the items stored in the combo boxes aswell, and i sadly cannot manually change the sizing of the items because they are bound in a layout it seems.

Can someone tell me whats going on here? Its not a big problem but its hurts to look at.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>711</width>
    <height>402</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>790</width>
    <height>402</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <property name="minimumSize">
    <size>
     <width>663</width>
     <height>0</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <property name="maximumSize">
    <size>
     <width>795</width>
     <height>414</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
      <item row="0" column="0">
       <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="InputLayout">
        <item alignment="Qt::AlignHCenter">
         <widget class="QLabel" name="Label_Input">
          <property name="text">
           <string>Input:</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QTextEdit" name="Text_Input">
          <property name="undoRedoEnabled">
           <bool>false</bool>
          </property>
          <property name="html">
           <string>&lt;!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC &quot;-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN&quot; &quot;http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd&quot;&gt;
&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;meta name=&quot;qrichtext&quot; content=&quot;1&quot; /&gt;&lt;style type=&quot;text/css&quot;&gt;
p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }
&lt;/style&gt;&lt;/head&gt;&lt;body style=&quot; font-family:'MS Shell Dlg 2'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;&quot;&gt;
&lt;p style=&quot;-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QComboBox" name="Combo_Input">
          <property name="enabled">
           <bool>true</bool>
          </property>
          <item>
           <property name="text">
            <string>Auto</string>
           </property>
          </item>
          <item>
           <property name="text">
            <string>en</string>
           </property>
          </item>
          <item>
           <property name="text">
            <string>de</string>
           </property>
          </item>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="1">
       <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="ButtonLayout">
        <item>
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="Button_Translate">
          <property name="text">
           <string>=&gt;</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="Button_Swap">
          <property name="text">
           <string>&lt;-&gt;</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="2">
       <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="OutputLayout">
        <item alignment="Qt::AlignHCenter">
         <widget class="QLabel" name="Label_Output">
          <property name="text">
           <string>Translated result:</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QTextBrowser" name="Text_Output">
          <property name="html">
           <string>&lt;!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC &quot;-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN&quot; &quot;http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd&quot;&gt;
&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;meta name=&quot;qrichtext&quot; content=&quot;1&quot; /&gt;&lt;style type=&quot;text/css&quot;&gt;
p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }
&lt;/style&gt;&lt;/head&gt;&lt;body style=&quot; font-family:'MS Shell Dlg 2'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;&quot;&gt;
&lt;p align=&quot;center&quot; style=&quot;-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QComboBox" name="Combo_Output">
          <item>
           <property name="text">
            <string>en</string>
           </property>
          </item>
          <item>
           <property name="text">
            <string>de</string>
           </property>
          </item>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Another big problem i stumbles into while trying to fix this is that i can no longer change the alignment of the comboboxes after breaking the layout and setting their minimum sizes - ***even after i ctrl+z back to where it was before!***

Comment: Please post the whole ui file so that others can test it in qt designer.

Comment: done, hope you can find something there...

Comment: I cannot reproduce this using the ui file you posted. For me, the two combo-boxes expand to fill the available space. What version of qt are you using, and on which platform?

Comment: Yes, it seems in my hurry of going home i pasted a slightly wrong .ui file, if you set both combo boxes to align right youll have the same as in the image i posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fix that by setting an higher value in the `minimumsize` section.
Try with minimum width=30px, for example.

> Edit: the problem was solved by avoiding the use of setAlignment, and replacing it by the use of QSpacer

Comment: I know, but that doesnt solve the big question, which is why this is even happening - i just tested further and it doesnt seem to be because one is a QTextEdit and the other a QTextBrowser, which means that the window should be symetric...

Comment: Are the combobox having the exact same properties? What are their contents?

Comment: Exactly the same. The contents are not the same right now, but i tried setting them the same, that didnt help.
Also, when i set both comboboxes to have a minimum size, it wont allow me to align them within the layout anymore, so i guess ill just have to leave it like that

* * * EDIT: This actually seems to be a bug - after breaking the layout and changing the minimum size, i cant even align them after ctrl+z to how it was before!

Comment: Are you using a QGridLayout? What if you try to replace it by a combination of a vertical and an horizonthal layout?

Comment: i only use grid for the main window, then 3 vertical columns for input, => / <=> and output and those 3 columns horizontally, grid layout i used so that the whole bunch resizes when the main window does - using vertical/horizontal alignment on main window screwed it all up for me

Comment: That's strange: when I download your file from pastebin I do not have your problem, and the combobox extend to the whole width... Maybe you should just create a new ui file and copy/paste the code of your current file in it?

Comment: it doesnt align at all? shit, maybe i pasted the wrong one - what happens if you set the 2 boxes on align left/right for yourself?

Comment: The combobox width stick to the length of it's first item (i.e. 'Auto' and 'en'). Try to avoid the use of setAlignment, insert an horizontal layout at the bottom of your columns and use a spacer: that's more easy to manipulate

Comment: ...but why is the combobox with the longer item SHORTER? Oo anyways thanks for the tip with the spacer, i didnt knew how to use those yet

Comment: The 'Auto' combobox was longer for me... So it seems we won't find out the reason it was in your project. If the spacer helps you to solve your problem, could you mark the question as solved?

Comment: Okay, i re-opened Qt-Designer and opened the file again, now they both are "as big as their content", so it looks good now. I guess "switch it on and off again" still stands as the best solution for everything 8)